# Can I run VMs in hyper V on a VHD Native booted Windows server 2012 R2 server

Tags: hyper-v

I have installed Windows server 2012 R2 in VHDX virtual disk and is using native VHD boot to boot up the server, I have installed the hyper v role in it. But upon on creating VMs it gives an error that "virtual machine failed to start. you need to enable Intel VT flag in bios". But VT has been enabled in the bios. I just need to know that we can use hyper v in a Native VHD booted server to make and run VMs.

Comment: You're saying that you've installed Server 2012 R2 on a VHDX. Are you trying to run Hyper-V on a virtual server?

Comment: Yes I am using the windows  native vhd boot feature to boot server 2012 r2 from vhdx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error "Virtual Machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running" on starting VMs in Hyper V.

I got fixed this by adding the below in my bootloader string.

**bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto**

and reboot the Server. After a reboot, all Virtual Machines can be started without Problems.

Comment: Does to put HV in auto mode, that it will be auto run when a VM is run and will not execute before that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a VHD within a VHD.

From [Understanding Virtual Hard Disks with Native Boot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825689.aspx) under "Limitations":

"- VHD files cannot be nested"

My guess is that's probably what you're running into.  Perhaps if you have a partition that's NOT a VHD, try targeting the Hyper-V VMs at that partition for storage.